# How could I get to Jamaica without going through US

Tags: routes, nigerian-citizens, jamaica

I m a Nigerian and I want to spend my two weeks holiday in Jamaica with a tourist

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You will need to connect in Europe or Canada, most likely; what has your initial research shown thus far?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the US? The reason is important: since alternatives can also be impacted by it

Answer (score 2):

You can fly to Montego Bay from Manchester, London, Brussels, Duesseldorf, Frankfurt, Munich, Milano and Verona and few more non-US locations in the Caribbean and central America. Also a dozen airport in Canada serve Montego Bay.

Most of the connections from Europe are charter/budget carriers, so you may have to split this into two trips.

A casual search showed non-US connections through Toronto (YYZ) with Air Canada, Egypt Air, Turkish, etc on a single ticket.

Comment: It might be worth noting that most of these options would require at least a transit visa, though I think they are all less costly than a US transit visa. Itineraries with a change of carrier could require a tourist visa.  Since you mention Egypt Air and Turkish, I believe that transit in both Egypt and Turkey would be possible without a visa, but I am less certain about Egypt.  Both seem rather far out of the way, however.  If the reason for avoiding the US is the no-fly list, though, Canada won't be an option since that won't avoid US airspace.